# Why memory address is not changed for different instances of struct?

Tags: swift, memory, struct

Since the `structs` are *value types* in *Swift*, so their memory is ofcourse allocated on the *stack*.

My question is, why is the memory address not changed when different instances of `struct` are assigned in the same variable.

**Explanation:**

For the below `struct`,

```
struct Person {
    var name: String

    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

if I create the instances of `Person` like,

```
var p = Person("John")
withUnsafePointer(to: &p) {
    print("\(p) has address: \($0)") //0x000000010dcea3c0
}
p = Person("Jennifer")
withUnsafePointer(to: &p) {
    print("\(p) has address: \($0)") //0x000000010dcea3c0
}
p = Person("Lisa")
withUnsafePointer(to: &p) {
    print("\(p) has address: \($0)") //0x000000010dcea3c0
}
```

Why is the same address printed everytime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using same variable. Take this example

var p (This is allocating memory to hold your value)

and now you are just changing the values and not the variable which is already been allocated to a memory location.

Comment: Then what about the content inside `p`? That'll have different address right?

Comment: @PGDev, within address you can update your content and thats what is happening here. So when you try printing content at this address, it will be updated.